# Запрос SQL на выборку значений содержащих букву

Tags: sql, postgresql, сопоставление-с-образцом

Имеется таблица с полем text, где содержатся как значения с буквой так и без (как пример: `а210,b210,c210... 210,211`). Как из всего массива данных вытащить только те которые начинаются с буквы?

Comment: Тег-спам удалён. Укажите точно свою СУБД. Одну. Включая её версию.

Comment: тебе нужно использовать LIKE

Comment: postgresql 7.0.4

Comment: Такой запрос, выдает ошибку:

SELECT * FROM book
where REGEXP_LIKE(text, '^([a-z]+$')



SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function regexp_like(character, unknown) does not exist
  Подсказка: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: А через like '%[^a-z]%'  не находит:(

Answer (score 2):

```sql
where substring('a210', 1, 1) ~ '[a-z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

В PostgreSQL существует несколько вариантов поиска по шаблону:

- [`~` или `~*` (независимо от регистра)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) (поддерживается в [PostgreSQL 7.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/functions-matching.html)):

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_text_col ~ '^[A-Za-z].*'
```

или

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_text_col ~* '^[a-z].*'
```

- оператор [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP):

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_text_col SIMILAR TO '[A-Za-z]%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7a9d7d/9)